# Sequence of continuous functions converging pointwise to a non-continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Is it possible that sequence of continuous functions is pointwise convergent to a non-continuous function?

Comment: I commented that Google will quickly find you an answer to this question on Wikipedia. Asking it on MSE with no indication that you have tried to solve the problem yourself is much less likely to be effective, but someone proved me wrong! I wish they hadn't.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Take $f_n(x) = e^{-(nx)^2}$. The limiting function $f$ is zero everywhere except at $x=0$, and $f(0)=1$ because $f_n(0)=1$ for all $n$.

In fact, each of the members of the sequence is $C^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly possible. The simplest example is probably $(x^n)$, which converges on $[0,1]$ to the function that is $0$ on $[0,1)$ and with value $1$ at $1$.

For the limit function $f$ to be continuous, a sufficient condition is the sequence to converge *uniformly* on every compact.